# exclude one specific url from Varnish Cache setting

Tags: nginx, centos, wordpress, varnish

What if I want to exclude only one specific url? e.g. mydomain.com/a. 
but this code not work properly.

```
    if ( req.url ~ "^/\?random" ) {
  return (pass);
}
```

I want to exclude only /a URL, I don't want to exclude mydomain.com/category or mydoamin.com/ask. ( all url have "a" character not cache in this config) 
I only want to exclude mydomain.com/a

anyone have a idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( req.url ~ "^/a/?($|\?)" ) {
  return (pass);
}
```

Will match, e.g.`/a` and `/a/`, and `/a?something=...`.
Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/CJrzcd/1).